# How to control the model binding security if i am passing an Object to a post edit Action method in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, security

i found a lot of examples and tutorial in professional websites that implement a post action method as follow by passing an Object instead of passing the object ID:-

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Album album)
{
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
db.Entry(album).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
return RedirectToAction(“Index”);
}
```

but on the other hand it is recommended for security reasons to define a Bind list on the model object level such as

```
[Bind(Include="Title,Description,genere")]
```

to prevent the model binding from manipulating object’s properties related to; ID , navigation properties or other properties such as createdby ,etc. and instead we should only
manipulate these particular properties using explicit code within our action methods.

**But the above approach of implementing the post action method by passing it a model object will conflict with defining a Bind list, so how i can handle such situation ?**

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to handle any situation, the `Bind` attribute will ensure that only these properties can be updated from the posted model.

Comment: thanks for the reply ,, but when i define [Bind(Include="Title,Description,genere")] , and i pass an object to the edit  post action method , then the post action method will raise an exception becuase the post action method need to bind the object ID and other properties not included in the Bind list!!!! So passing a model object to an action method will conflict with defining a Bind list. so my question was if it is possible to remove this conflict by having a bind list in addtion to passing an object to the action method. BR

Comment: Please could you post the full exception? Ta.